# Extract data from company sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, sharepoint, scrapinghub

Can I extract data from company's sharepoint using python.

Used power automate but I want to use python code

Answer (score 0):

If you have a download link/url you can use requests to get the raw data and save it to a local excel file.

```
import requests

url = "..."

response = requests.get(url)
with open('my_file.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Then you can use pandas or so to read the file.